# Nativescript: Element in StackLayout is sometimes not rendered/visible although it is clickable and on top of other elements in the StackLayout

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

Oke, it sounds very confusing, and it is to me.

In the template we use a ContentView element. In the controller the `ComponentFactoryResolver` is used to get a dynamic component and place it into the ContentView.

The controller: (simplified)

```
@ViewChild('fieldtype', {static: false, read: ViewContainerRef }) viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

loadComponent() {
    let fieldComponent;

    ... // Some logic to get fieldComponent

    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(fieldComponent);
    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

}
```

And the template:
[image]

This is how it looks like most of the time:
[image]

But, sometimes it looks like this:
[image]

When I inspect the XML it is showing the XML markup of the control. The markup is exactly the same when the control is visible:
[image]

What makes it REALLY strange is that when I click between the top of the text 'test' and the last horizontal line the `(tab)` event in the dynamically loaded component is fired. (The `(tab)` event of the test button is not triggered.)

This would suggest that the control is on top of all other elements in the StackLayout, but isn't rendered correctly.

Does anyone might have an idea how this is possible? I've tried various things like playing with timeouts to trigger change detection. Or waited a couple of seconds after the ContentView loaded() event was triggered before resolving the dynamic component. And many more without any success...

The hard thing is that most of the time it is working as it should, but 1 out of 10 times this strange behavior shows up and I can't find what is different from the other 9 times.

I'm stuck on this problem for over a week now and I'm running out of ideas how to fix this issue, any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced. Besides, may I ask why don't you simply go with ngIf here? seems to me that you need just a component rendered conditionally but let me know otherwise.

Comment: I will try yo make a playground sample, but it may take me some time due to the size of the app... The ngIf directive is not that practical when there are over 40 different components that could be shown in that position.